# EJB 3.0 timer bean timeout called multiple times in glassfish

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-5, glassfish-2.x

We have to implement EJB 3.0 timers and we took the following approach:

- we created @Stateless beans and injected the TimerService with the @Resource annotation
- we have implemented a servlet which calls an initialization method during startup

The following snipets should be able to give you a more clear picture:

The timer implementation:

```
public class TimerFacade {

  @Resource
  protected TimerService timerService;

  public void createTimer() {
    timerService.createTimer(startTime, intervall, ident);
  }
}
```

The init servlet:

```
public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @EJB
  private transient ITimerFacade timerFacade;

  @Override
  public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    timerFacade.createTimer();
  }
}
```

After a (re-)deployment everything is fine. But after a restart it happens that the glassfish (2.1) gives us following message:

```
Rescheduling missed expiration for periodic timer ...
```

How could we avoid this behaviour and how could we guarantee that the timer is only started once?

We have to tried to make a stateless bean with a timer service injected to let us give the currrently available timers. But the timer which will be rescheduled from the container doesn't come up in this list cause the container reschedules the persisted timers at the end of initialization of the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

EJB Timers are persistent, which means if you did not cancel the timer it will continue working once the server is up.

You should cancel the timer either when the application is shutting down (not sure how you do that in glassfish) or before you create a new timer check if that timer already exists.

Comment: thanks for your hints. problem is that the jee container doesn't guarantee that a stateless session bean is always up and running means a stateless session bean can be destroyed by a container even the application is running. therefore I don't like the idea to add a predestroy hook to it. during startup we are too early in the lifecyle cause glassfish reschedules the timers after the whole application has been initialized.

Comment: Isee that at startup you already got access to that EJB, if you are able to create timers you can also get running timers and cancel them before creating one (or just identify you got a timer and don't create a new one)

Comment: yes that's the point. during startup when we create the timer we have at this point of time only access to the actual timers and not the persisted ones. after everything was set up by the container the glassfish comes up with a message like "Rescheduling missed expiration for periodic timer" and the problem is only after this rescheduling message all timers are registered at the timer service. during startup the timer service has not the "old" timers.

Comment: one idea in the beginning was to configure an init servlet at the beginning of the start fetching the "old" timer over the timer service and cancel them all. but this doesn't seem to workl.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Does getTimers not return the timers, or are the timers firing before you have a chance to cancel them?

Comment: if we want to cancel them during startup the application it seems to be too early. glassfish starts the "old" timers after the startup and initialization process was done (which seems to make sense).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.... to ensure ObjectTimer run one at time i used sort of semaphore, a static boolean variable ENABLE_TIMER wich i use in @Timeout method:

```
@Timeout
public void timerMethod(Timer timer) {
    try{
    if (ObjectModelSessionBean.ENABLE_TIMER ) {
        timerMethod();
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("timer is temporary disabled - waiting....);
    }
    }catch (Exception ex){
         LOGGER.severe("- Eccezione.   "+ex.toString());
    }
}
```

at the beginnig of timerMethod() I set variable ENABLE_TIMER to false, at the end ENABLE_TIMER is set to true